# Tableview with searcher - Searching works good, but selecting element displays wrong element

Tags: arrays, swift, search, textview, element

I'm having a problem with a tableView where I display some values for the user to choose. It is connected with a search-bar that filters the contents in an array displayed in the TableView.

So the problem is as follows:
When I search for an element, the tableView filters perfectly, displaying the correct element. But if I decide to choose this element, it will display the first element that were showed from beginning, i.e. from loading all the elements into the textView. It's like my tableView only displays the text but not the correct indexPath when searching.

Here is the code:

```
    extension SelectCityViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return searchCity.count
        } else {
            return citiesItems.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        if searching {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = searchCity[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = citiesItems[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        toastMessage(message: "\(citiesItems[indexPath.row]) selected")
        SelectCityViewController.selectedCity="\(citiesItems[indexPath.row])"
        self.removeAnimate()
    }

}

extension SelectCityViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchCity = citiesItems.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: start var names with small letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether the state is `searching` / not  in `didSelectRowAt`

```
if searching {
   selectCityViewController.selectedCity = searchCity[indexPath.row]
 }
 else {
   selectCityViewController.selectedCity = citiesItems[indexPath.row]
 }
```

A short way also

```
selectCityViewController.selectedCity = searching ? searchCity[indexPath.row] : citiesItems[indexPath.row]
```

Also if type of `searchCity[indexPath.row]` / `citiesItems[indexPath.row]` is `String`  then no need for `"\()"`

Comment: Thank you very much sir.